# Sitecore's Field.HasValue returning false, even when there is a Value?

Tags: c#, razor, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm attempting to use Sitecore's `Field.HasValue` property in Razor syntax to test a particular field, but no matter what I try, the field always seems to be false.

- I'm using Sitecore 8.
- The Sitecore field, *"Header Number"* is a Single-Line Text field

Here's what I'm trying:

```
@{
    var phoneNumber = "";
    var numberField = Model.Item.Fields["Header Number"];
    if (numberField != null && numberField.HasValue)
    {
        phoneNumber = numberField.Value;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below:

- `numberField` is being correctly set to a Sitecore Field
- `numberField.HasValue` is reporting `false`
- **However** `numberField.Value` is (correctly) returning the value of the field
- Because of the failure to fire the `if` block, `phoneNumber` is never set:

[image: Screenshot of Breakpoint showing variable values]

Is this a bug? Am I using `HasValue` incorrectly or is there another Sitecore method I should be using to safely test if fields have a value?

Comment: Can you not check `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(numberField)` in your `if` block ?

Comment: @jammykam - I probably can this time, seeing as it's a String, but I'm more worried about the more complex data types that Sitecore supports and that I'm using `.HasValue` on elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably value of this field comes from the Standard Values item (is inherited).

`HasValue` property only returns true when the value is set on the item itself.

Here is the implementation of `HasValue` property:

```cs
public bool HasValue
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetValue(false, false) != null;
  }
}

public string GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue)
{
  ...
}
```

You can check `ContainsStandardValue` property to check if the value comes from the Standard Values.

Comment: @MarekMusielak : Is ContainsStandardValue property exposed by nullable type itself?

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 this has nothing to do with nullable type. `Field` type is not nullable. It's Sitecore class and it has `HasValue` property.

Comment: It appears calling `ContainsStandardValues` **after** calling `HasValue` has [a different result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SE0Hq.png) compared to if we call `ContainsStandardValues` beforehand. Just a heads up, I had to watch the order of operations when testing against both

Comment: Strange, because this should not happen. Although, in case it was happening in the past, it is not happening now. I am checking this with Sitecore 10.1.0 version and whether I call ContainsStandardValues before or after HasValue, there is no difference.

Comment: @Varun - good to know. If I recall correctly, this project was Sitecore 8.